# вывод разницы значений в pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вывести таблицу из этой чтоб вместо текущих значений в строках была разница между текущей и следующей строкой.  например если в первой строк 10 во второй 11, а в третей 15,  то чтоб в первой стало 1, во второй 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Датафрейм:

```
    a
0  10
1  11
2  15
3  18
```

1. простой метод `diff()`, судя по задаче, он вам не подойдет:

```
df['a'].diff()
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    4.0
3    3.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

2. `diff()` c отрицательным периодом:

```
df['a'].diff(periods=-1).abs()
0    1.0
1    4.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

3. `diff()` со сдвигом:

```
df['a'].diff().shift(-1)
0    1.0
1    4.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
```